# Meteor.js error when trying to run android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having an error when trying to run code meteor run android as you can see on the image below.

Any suggestion why this happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out before running the command meteor run android, the android emulator must be turn on manually first. That's what happen actually, which is I don't have any running emulator that's causing the error to happen

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually run the command

`cd D:\Android\sdk\tools\bin
avdmanager.bat list target`

If that doesn't work, there is some issue with your Android installation.